# Haskell code explanation

Tags: haskell

```
xs = [1,2,3]::[Float]
ys = map (+) xs
```

This was a question in an old test and there is no solution sheet.

The questions:

1) What kind of signature does `ys` have?

2) Explain why and draw how `ys` looks like

For the first question I know that `xs` is of type `float` and so should `ys`(I run the program in ghci too).
As for the second one I have no idea, because when I run the code nothing happens. When I run it and the run `ys` on a separate row I get an error.

Can someone help me with a hint?

Answer (score 3):

> For the first question I know that `xs` is of type `float`

er, no. `xs` has type `[Float]`: a *list* of floats.

> and so should `ys`

`ys` does **not** have the same type as `xs`. You probably think so because you've read that `+` requires the arguments and result to have the same type:

```
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

...or if you instantiate it to `Float` numbers

```
(+) :: Float -> Float -> Float
```

This is correct, nevertheless `(+)` is not an [endomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endomorphism) (a function mapping a type to itself, as it would have to be if `ys` was the same type as `xs`) because it has *two* number arguments.

With `map (+)` you're considering `(+)` as a function of *a single argument*, not of two arguments. In most programming languages this would actually be an error, but not so in Haskell: in Haskell, *all* functions actually have only one argument. Functions with “multiple arguments” are really just [functions on interesting types, that make it seem as if you're passing multiple arguments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). In particular, the signature of `(+)` is actually shorthand for:

```
(+) :: Float -> (Float -> Float)
```

So, considered as a one-argument function, `(+)` actually maps numbers to number-endomorphisms. Hence,

```
map (+) :: [Float] -> [Float -> Float]
```

and

```
ys :: [Float -> Float]
```

– a list of number-functions. Specifically, it's this list:

```
ys = [(+) 1    , (+) 2    , (+) 3    ]
   ≡ [(1+)     , (2+)     , (3+)     ]
   ≡ [\n -> 1+n, \n -> 2+n, \n -> 3+n]
```

I could, for example, use it like this:

```
GHCi> let [f,g,h] = ys in [f 3, g 2, h 1]
[4,4,4]
GHCi> map ($ 10) ys -- applies all functions separately to the number 10
[11,12,13]
GHCi> foldr ($) 0 ys -- applies all the functions one after another to 0
6
```

BTW, IMO you're asking the question the wrong way around. In Haskell, you don't want to consider some code and wonder what type it has – that is more an ML or even Lisp approach. I'd always start with the type signature, and work out the implementation “outside to in” ([typed holes](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Typed_holes) are very handy for this). This possibility is one of the big advantages of functional programming in comparison to procedural languages.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have ghci at the moment, apologies if something I say is wrong.

`xs` is type `[Float]` and `ys` is of type `[Float -> Float]`(it's a list of functions that each take a `Float` and return a `Float`). `ys` will be `[(+) 1, (+) 2, (+) 3]` because `map` applies `(+)` to each elements in `xs`. But you cannot print `ys` because functions do not derive `Show`

Comment: what exactly is it that is being added to the list?

Comment: I think you are asking what `ys` means. It's a list of 3 functions, the first function is just `f x = x+1`, the second one is `f x = x+2` ...

Comment: As Priyatham states, nothing is added to the list. Each member of the list is applied a function (so a function is called with it being the first argument) and the results are returned in another list.  Enter currying: `+` is a single argument function (all in Haskell are), that returns another single-argument function.

Answer (score 1):

ys type is `[Float -> Float]`, a list of functions that receive a number return the number +1 (first elem), the number + 2 (the second) and the number +3 (the last).

Please, bear in mind that `+` is a is applied with a single argument for each list element so it does return another function.

If you wanted to add all the items in the List, you should use a reduce function, such as `foldl`.

`let zs = foldl (+) 0 xs`

I hope this helps.

Cristóbal